# Html table with width 100% does not work with long text

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following structure

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td style="width:60px;">
        ...
    </td>
    <td>
        <div style="width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;">
            PROBLEMS ARE HERE
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

The first td takes 60px, the second one takes the rest of the 100%, but when I have some long text with no spaces and no dashes the table becomes larger then the 100%.
How to display the non-breakable text in one line or on multiple lines (both ways are acceptable) and keep the table on 100% of the screen?
I've tried to fix this with overflow-hidden but it has no effect.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:[link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/27/problemruf.jpg/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set `table-layout : fixed` in your css or `<table style='table-layout : fixed'>` that oughta fix it.

Here is the [code sample](http://jsfiddle.net/EY8SC/1/). Check it out.

Answer (score 6):

There is a CSS3 property, `word-wrap:break-word;` that does exactly what you need. But unfortunately it doesn't work with table cells. I think you need to rethink your structure, opting for a table-less design.

I wrote this example for you

```
<style>
section { /* your table */
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#aaf;
}
section:after {display:block; content:''; clear:left}

div { /* your cells */
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#faa;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
</style>

<section>
    <div>Content.</div>
    <div>Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong cat.</div>
</section>
```

P.S: `word-wrap` is supported in IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.5+, and WebKit browsers such as Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 6):

try the following:

```
<table style="word-break:break-all;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td style="width:60px;">
        ...
    </td>
    <td>
        <div style="width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;">
            PROBLEMS ARE no longer HERE !
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```